# UIImagePicker not returning images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The associated view contains a circular image view in which the user taps a button and selects an image then that image is set to that image views corresponding image. If I attempt to force-unwrap the optional in saveChanges it returns an error saying only nil was found during runtime. Been battling this for a couple days. Definitely at my wits end.

```
import UIKit

class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var editBio: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var editFullName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var chosenImage: UIImageView!
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        makeRounded(imageView: chosenImage)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func imagePicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                chosenImage.image = selectedImage
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func saveChanges(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        if let newChosenImage = chosenImage.image {
            ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.profilePicture = newChosenImage
        } else {
            print("uugghhh")
        }
        ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.fullName = editFullName.text!
        ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.description = editBio.text!
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])`

should be outside of `@IBAction func imagePicked(_ sender: UIButton)` 's scope

use the following code

```
@IBAction func imagePicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        
        
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                chosenImage.image = selectedImage
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

instead of

```
@IBAction func imagePicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        // it should not be within ` @IBAction func imagePicked(`
        // it should be outside  ` @IBAction func imagePicked(`
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                chosenImage.image = selectedImage
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

then OK

Answer (score 0):

I can see that delegate method of picker controller is written inside button it should be outside of button scope, please compare this to your posted code

```
class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var editBio: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var editFullName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var chosenImage: UIImageView!
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        makeRounded(imageView: chosenImage)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func imagePicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }}
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                chosenImage.image = selectedImage
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    
    @IBAction func saveChanges(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        if let newChosenImage = chosenImage.image {
            ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.profilePicture = newChosenImage
        } else {
            print("uugghhh")
        }
        ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.fullName = editFullName.text!
        ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.description = editBio.text!
    }
```